# Variance of a random variable X+Y when X=Y

Tags: statistics, expectation, covariance

I know that $Var(aX)=a^2Var(X)$ and that $Var(X+Y)=Var(X)+Var(Y)$.

**When $X=Y$ why is the following not true?**

$Var(X+Y)=Var(X+X)=Var(2X)$

$Var(X+X)=Var(X)+Var(X)$ and $Var(2X)=2^2Var(X)=4Var(X)$

$\therefore Var(X)+Var(X)=4Var(X)$

I understand that this could be that $X+X$ is not equal to $2X$ when it comes to variances but
**how do you know which to use?**

Thanks

Comment: $Var(X+Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y)$ is only correct if $Cov(X,Y) = 0$. But $Cov(X,X) = Var(X) > 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{equation}
var(X+Y) = E[((X+Y)-E(X+Y))((X+Y)-E(X+Y))']
\end{equation}
  Assuming $X,Y$ to be scalar random variables, we get,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
var(X+Y) &= E[((X-E(X)) + (Y-E(Y)))^2]\\
&= E[(X-E(X))^2 + (Y-E(Y))^2 + 2\times (X-E(X)) (Y-E(Y))]\\
&=E[(X-E(X))^2] + E[(Y-E(Y))^2] + E[2\times (X-E(X)) (Y-E(Y))]\\
&=var(X)+var(Y)+2cov(X,Y)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
 so only when $cov(X,Y) = 0$, $var(X+Y) = var(X)+var(Y)$

Answer (score 2):

Just to complement the other answers, the general form of the formula you are trying to use is:

$$
\mathrm{Var}(aX+bY)=a^2\mathrm{Var}(X)+b^2\mathrm{Var}(Y)+2ab\, \mathrm{Cov}(X,Y),
$$

which follows from the definitions of variance and covariance.

Answer (score 1):

The relation $Var(X+Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y)$ only holds for uncorrelated variables. Obviously, $X$ is correlated to $X$!